# Unable to Initialize SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a class A this class does not extend or implement any other classes. I then have an Class B, this class also does not extend or implement any other classes.

My Class B is solely used to manage `SharedPreferences` :

```
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```

Here is the problem method in Class B:

```
public static void setCurrentUsersEmail(String email){
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userEmail",email).commit();
}
```

Now class A is a database manager and needs to store the users email in `SharedPreferences` for later use. I do this with the following code:`

```
MySharedPrefs.setCurrentUsersEmail(currentUsersEmail);
```

However, when i try run the code in Class A i get the error:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                                             at com.test.Android.MySharedPrefs.setCurrentUsersEmail(MySharedPrefs.java:0)

I am really confused as to why this happens I couldn't find a solution online after searching either, I use my sharedPreferences class in other **activities** perfectly fine. Is it an activity problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how you pass `mContext` inside `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` method

Comment: So I call `setCurrentUsersEmail(currentUsersEmail)` from a recyclerview adapter. This then goes to class A where the database is checked and then the SharedPreferences is called. When the sharedPreferences is originally created I call a method from MainActivity to get its context data. I dont think the context is being sent in this instance though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use singleton for your requirement  :

```
public class MyPrefs {

    private static MyPrefs myPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private MyPrefs(Context context){

        sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static MyPrefs getInstance(Context context){

        if(myPrefs==null)
            myPrefs=new MyPrefs(context);
        return myPrefs;
    }

    public void setCurrentUsersEmail(String email){

        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userEmail",email).commit();
    }
}
```

You can put email in this way :

```
MyPrefs.getInstance(context).setCurrentUsersEmail(currentUsersEmail);
```

You need to pass context at first time for the reference of `sharedPreferences` in your Class.

or

From Activity call `MyPrefs.getInstance(context)` at once

Then you can call without context

```
MyPrefs.getInstance().setCurrentUsersEmail(currentUsersEmail);
```

`getInstance()` method :

```
public static MyPrefs getInstance(){

      if(myPrefs==null) throw new AssertionError("MyPrefs cannot be null");
      else 
      return myPrefs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Could you please explain why it fails to get sharedPreferencces from the MainActivity in this instance?

Comment: First of all static variable should be initialise in static block and **PreferenceManager** -> Used to help create Preference hierarchies from activities or XML and **SharedPreferences** -> Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by getSharedPreferences(String, int). For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share.

Comment: `PreferenceManager` is normally used when you want to create a PreferenceActivity or load in some Preferences from an .xml file in your application with default values, and holds it's own referenced to SharedPreferences

Comment: `static variable should be initialise in static block` <- I already do this.. and okay rest makes sense thanks so much

Comment: @memoryManagers You get an `ExceptionInInitializerError` if something goes wrong in the static block like any exception of something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this , in any activity, dont need to create a new method:

To save:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("email", "YOURUSEREMAIL@.email");
 editor.commit();
```

To restore:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("email", null);
```

You cant call MyPrefs.aFunctionYouCreated() !!!